# Stompclient/ SockJs - Receiving messages multiple times through 1-1 broker channel

Tags: websocket, stomp, sockjs

I am working on a chat module, for which backend is Java and frontend is Angular. The process of chat works like this:

1. Connect to stomp client
2. subscribe to channel url for e.g is: `queue/user-{userId}`
3. Save message to server using `stompclient->send('savemessage', {}, message)`
4. Server sends acknowledgement, that message is saved
5. I send message to user from broker channel for e.g. `stompclient->send('queue/user-{toUserId}', {}, message)`
6. The `toUserId` if subscribed using `queue/user-{toUserId}` in channel, then he receives the message.
   It works fine, when `toUserId` is connected and subscribed only once. Problem comes, when I open another connection and subscribe for `toUserId` in different browser or mobile application.

Problem is:
userId send message once, but `toUserId` is getting messages 2 times as open 2 connections/subscriptions.
Anyone gone through such situation earlier?

Following are screenshots:

1. Receiving message:
   [image: Receiving message]
2. Send message:
   [image: Send message]

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple chats, you should have multiple **stompclient**, one for each chat (conection)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).